# Как лучше организовать архитектуру в react приложении когда очень много мелких проектов?

Tags: reactjs, архитектура

Нужно делать небольшие проекты для сайта (например табличка, карусель, фотогалерея + табличка + текст, графики, карты мира, разные уникальные проекты с индивидуальной вёрсткой).
Но использовать общие компоненты react. Время для разработки проекта может быть от 2-3 часов до пары дней. В год около 100-150 проектов получается.

И копировать готовый js файл каждого проекта на разные сервера (test, dev, work)
Пожать его(только для work сервера), проанализировать код например JSLint, запускать тесты.

Можно для каждого проекта создавать отдельное react приложение со своей настройкой.
1. но не хочется плодить множество в каждой папке node_modules
2. Не хочется возиться с настройкай каждого проекта, они отличаются только используемыми компонентами и конечной папкой для копирования файла.

Раньше использовался сборщик gulp + MVC фреймворк для этого. Там это просто настраивалось. Каждый проект это отдельная задача и разные MVC компоненты собирались в 1 файл, который копировался на разные сервера.

```
gulp.task('fifa-2018-calendar', function() {
    gulp.src([
            mvcBuildFolder + mvcBaseFile,

            projectFolder + '/projects/sport/fifa-2018/fifa-2018-calendar/models/fifa-2018-calendar-model.js',
            projectFolder + '/projects/sport/fifa-2018/fifa-2018-calendar/views/fifa-2018-calendar-view.js',
            projectFolder + '/projects/sport/fifa-2018/fifa-2018-calendar/controllers/fifa-2018-calendar-controller.js'
        ])
        .pipe(jshint()).pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(concat('js_projects/sport/fifa-2018/fifa-2018-calendar/fifa-2018-calendar.1.0.3.js'))     
        .pipe(gulp.dest(localGitFolder))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(testFolder))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(devFolder))

        //.pipe(stripDebug())  - перед копированием на рабочий идёт сжатие проекта
        //.pipe(uglify())
        //.pipe(gulp.dest(workFolder))
});
```

Но сейчас хочется перейти на react и компонентный подход, уйти от MVC. 
Но при этом хочется сохранить простоту и автоматизацию разработки которая была у gulp. Но не могу понять как это организовать на webpack, хочу посмотреть на рабочий пример кода.

---

Хорошо, попробую по другому объяснить.

Ну вот есть сайт на котором публикуются различные новости (проекты). 
И нужно организовать такую архитектуру чтобы было удобно быстро публиковать такие проекты.
Это должен быть 1 репозиторий. Создание и публикация проекта должны занимать минимум времени.
То есть пришло задание сделать проект с 1 таблицей, картой мира и свёрстанным блоком поиска по карте.
Дедлайн 2 дня. На выходе нужен js файл который будет помещен на страницу с этой новостью.
Потом через день приходит задание сделать проект с картой мира с другими данными без поиска и вставить в другую новость.
Через 2 дня пришло задание поменять некоторые данные в проекте который разрабатывались 2 года назад, там обновилась информация в таблице с данными по процентным ставкам банков.

Раньше использовалась MVC архитектура и собственный фреймворк. Верстальщик передаёт вёрстку и программист это засовывает во view, пишет model и controller файлы на js.
 Сейчас хочется перейти на react. И главный вопрос как организовать сборщик проектов под такую задачу.

Comment: вы как-будто из прошлого! Сленг и ход мыслей вообще не поход на человека, который участвует от 100 до 150 проектов в год. Есть сборщики, репозитории, npm, storybook. Не очень понятно о чем вы вообще.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Такой подход не используется. Вы пытаетесь натянуть парадигму статического сайта на теперишние инструменты. Вам нужно думалку менять. И MVC тут не причем. А ответ конкретно на ваш вопрос будет "используйте continuous integration and delivery"

Comment: webpack, continuous integration, dynamic import.

Comment: А есть конкретные примеры hello world 
"webpack + continuous integration"?
А то технологий очень много, реализаций тоже. 
Хочется увидеть хороший рабочий код применительно к react.
Про continuous integration я уже давно слышал и читал, но как раз ищу хорошую статью или книгу или курс по этому, а не просто фразы.

Comment: Чтобы пойти дальше фраз, вы сначала должны подумать, что хотите найти. Наверняка, кто-то, превосходным образом описал созданием утюга. Ну и что? Вы будите подход утюга натягивать при создании своей соковарки? Или вы думаете будет прям создать "то-то и то-то" когда один чел сто раз в год карты заливает?

Comment: Ну вроде описал что хочу найти. Инструмент для быстрой разработки самых разных мини проектов. То есть  получать готовый js файл и копировать его на сервера. И чтобы этот процесс не был сложным и  долгим.